# Make jquery ignore href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append data into a `div` tag using jquery when there is a click event on `a` html tag,html and javascript code is below and live example for same is at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4ur4v/X5gcj/)

HTML

```
<a class="datafile" href="#">abc</a>
<div id="result2">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".datafile").click(function() {
$('#result2').append('Clicked!');   
}
```

When a user clicks on `abc` I dont want the browser to go to link in `href` rather it should insert `Clicked!` in div tag.

What I am doing wrong ? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(".datafile").click(function(e) {
    $('#result2').append('Loading Log File ...');   

    // For all modern browsers, prevent default behavior of the click
    e.preventDefault();

    // Just to be sure, older IE's needs this
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to prevent the default action of the hyperlink.

```
$('.datafile').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the href value from '#' to 'javascript:void(0);'?